# Get current number of partitions of a DataFrame

Tags: python, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any way to get the current number of partitions of a DataFrame?
I checked the DataFrame javadoc (spark 1.6) and didn't found a method for that, or am I just missed it? 
(In case of JavaRDD there's a getNumPartitions() method.)

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You need to call `getNumPartitions()` on the DataFrame's underlying RDD, e.g., `df.rdd.getNumPartitions()`.  In the case of Scala, this is a parameterless method: `df.rdd.getNumPartitions`.

Comment: minus the (), so not entirely correct - at least not with SCALA mode

Comment: Does this cause a *conversion* (_expensive_) from `DF` to `RDD` ?

Comment: This IS expensive

Comment: @javadba Do you have an answer that doesn't appeal to the RDD API?

Comment: No I do not: and it is unfortunate that spark does not manage the metadata better along the lines of hive.  Your answer is correct but also is my observation that this is costly.

Comment: And about Hive tables, make sense to convert to RDD to get number of partitions? Supposing same result in Hive `show patitions tatbleName`, but `rdd.getNumPartions` better performance (and more elegant).

Comment: can we get partition number in map function ? such as `rdd.map{ r => this.partitionNum }`  ?

Answer (score 30):

`dataframe.rdd.partitions.size` is another alternative apart from `df.rdd.getNumPartitions()` or `df.rdd.length`.

let me explain you  this with full example...

```
val x = (1 to 10).toList
val numberDF = x.toDF(“number”)
numberDF.rdd.partitions.size // => 4
```

**To prove that how many number of partitions we got with above... save that dataframe as csv**

```
numberDF.write.csv(“/Users/Ram.Ghadiyaram/output/numbers”)
```

Here is how the data is separated on the different partitions.

```
Partition 00000: 1, 2
Partition 00001: 3, 4, 5
Partition 00002: 6, 7
Partition 00003: 8, 9, 10
```

## Update :

> @Hemanth asked a good question in the comment... basically why number
>   of partitions are 4 in above case

***Short answer :*** Depends on cases where you are executing. since local[4] I used, I got 4 partitions.

***Long answer :***

I was running above program in my local machine and  used master as local[4] based on that it was taking as **4** partitions.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName(this.getClass.getName)
    .config("spark.master", "local[4]").getOrCreate()
```

If its spark-shell in master yarn I got the number of partitions as 2

example : `spark-shell --master yarn` and typed same commands again

```
scala> val x = (1 to 10).toList
x: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)


scala> val numberDF = x.toDF("number")
numberDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [number: int]

scala> numberDF.rdd.partitions.size
res0: Int = 2
```

- here 2 is [default parllelism of spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#execution-behavior)
- Based on hashpartitioner spark will decide how many number of partitions to distribute. if you are running in `--master local` and based on your `Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors()` 
  i.e. `local[Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors()]` it will try to allocate
  those number of partitions. if your available number of processors are 12 (i.e. `local[Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors()])` and you have list of 1 to 10 then only 10 partitions will be created.

> ## NOTE:
>
> ***If you are  on a 12-core laptop where I am executing spark program and by default the number of partitions/tasks is the number of all available cores i.e. 12. that
>   means `local[*]` or
>   `s"local[${Runtime.getRuntime.availableProcessors()}]")` but in this
>   case only 10 numbers are there so it will limit to 10***

keeping all these pointers in mind I would suggest you to try on your own

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I am curious why a list of 10 numbers was divided into 4 partitions when converted to a DF. Can you kindly provide some explanation, please?

Comment: Is this `since local[4] I used, I got 4 partitions.` still valid for 3.x? I've got 200 partitions with local[4].

Comment: @Sergey Bushmanov : [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57385715/647053) also [spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#execution-behavior)

Comment: The 2 links you provided are indeed confirming that current number of partitions is different from `local[n]`. Actually, that num partitions has little to do with `local[n]` is expected due to the map/reduce parallelism.

Comment: can we get partition number in map function ? such as rdd.map{ r => this.partitionNum } ?

Comment: I am seeing errors: `'RDD' object has no attribute 'partitions'` for `df.rdd.partitions.size` (spark v3.2.1)

Answer (score 10):

convert to RDD then get the partitions length

```
DF.rdd.partitions.length
```

Comment: can we get partition number in map function ? such as rdd.map{ r => this.partitionNum } ?

Answer (score 6):

```
 val df = Seq(
  ("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("A", 3), ("C", 1)
).toDF("k", "v")

df.rdd.getNumPartitions
```

Comment: Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for providing quality answer.

Comment: can we get partition number in map function ? such as rdd.map{ r => this.partitionNum } ?

Answer (score 0):

One more Interesting way to get number of partitions is 'using mapPartitions' transformation.
Sample Code -

```
val x = (1 to 10).toList
val numberDF = x.toDF()
numberDF.rdd.mapPartitions(x => Iterator[Int](1)).sum()
```

Spark experts are welcome to comment on its performance.

Comment: can we get partition number in map function ? such as rdd.map{ r => this.partitionNum } ?