# spark dataframe groupBy task number

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I run at local mode and init with 2 partition.
when I use DataFrame.show(), it gets like this: `INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 5) in 390 ms on localhost (2/2)`.
But when I use DataFrame.groupBy(), it gets so many tasks just like this:`INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 83.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 691) in 644 ms on localhost (84/200)`. 
My source code is here.

```
everyIResDF.show()
val resDF = everyIResDF
  .groupBy("dz_id","dev_id","dev_type","time")
  .avg("IRes")
resDF.show()
```

I want to know why groupBy() would cause this matter and how to solve it.
Any help is useful.

Comment: What is your problem? That the number of tasks increase a lot when using `groupBy()`? It's an expensive operation that requires a complete reshuffle of your data.

Comment: I see it's not a good way to use groupBy(). I just want to know the rule how tasks create and why cause too many task number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A task will be launch for each partition you have in each stage. You initialize the dataframe with 2 partitions, hence, the number of tasks will be low (2) for your first `INFO` print.

However, each time there Spark needs to perform a shuffle of the data it will decide and change how many partitions the shuffle RDD will have. The default value is 200. Therefore, after using `groupBy()` which requires a full data shuffle, the number of tasks will have increased to 200 (as seen in your second `INFO` print).

The number of partitions to use when shuffling data can be set by changing Spark's configuration, for example to set it to 4, simply do:

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "4”)
```

By running the code with this configuration you will no longer see such a high number of tasks. The optimal number of partitions depends on many things but can heuristically be set to 3 or 4 times your number of cores.

Comment: It helps me a lot !  If my application has many place to shuffle data, can I change the  `shuffle.partitions`  when application is running ?  And at spark-submit, is this conf'key `spark.shuffle.sort.bypassMergeThreshold` ?

Comment: @ulysses I believe the easiest way would be to set the number of partitions on the dataframe itself by doing `df.repartition(numOfPartitions)`. For the spark-submit the key is still `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` although you may want to set `spark.default.parallelism` aswell, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704156/spark-sql-shuffle-partitions-and-spark-default-parallelism/45704560#45704560.

Comment: Get it . where are these confs come from? I only see some conf at `http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html`

Comment: The sql conf can be found here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html. The other rdd one is from the page you have.