# Clarity on number of partitions in spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema = StructType([StructField("type", StringType(), True), StructField("average", IntegerType(), True)])
values = [('A', 19), ('B', 17), ('C', 10)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(values, schema)

parts = df.rdd.getNumPartitions()

print(parts)
```

Output is 44

**How is spark creating 44 partitions for 3 records dataframe?**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.withColumn('p_id', F.spark_partition_id()).show()
```

Output :

```
+----+-------+----+
|type|average|p_id|
+----+-------+----+
|   A|     19|  14|
|   B|     17|  29|
|   C|     10|  43|
+----+-------+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

When Dataset/Dataframe is created out of a collection it does take rows number into account.
Eventually it comes down to `LocalTableScanExec`, look [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/LocalTableScanExec.scala#L48)

```
numParallelism: Int = math.min(math.max(unsafeRows.length, 1),  sqlContext.sparkContext.defaultParallelism)
rdd = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(unsafeRows, numParallelism)
```

Where `unsafeRows.length` equals to the provided collection size.

Also, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704156/what-is-the-difference-between-spark-sql-shuffle-partitions-and-spark-default-pa) answer for several related settings.

Answer (score 0):

Cause Spark initially create N number of partitions regardless of data. For example, I've run Spark locally with "local[4]" and create a DF from 2 rows
`df.rdd().getNumPartitions()` would return 4, cause there is 4 cores for Spark job.

If I do the next:

```
df.repartition(2).rdd().getNumPartitions()
```

result would be 2.