# Pyspark: org.apache.spark.memory.SparkOutOfMemoryError: Unable to acquire 116 bytes of memory, got 0

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
spark_config = {
#     'spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled': 'true',
    'spark.driver.memory': '5g',
    'spark.driver.maxResultSize': '5g',
    'spark.executor.memory': '4g',
    'spark.executor.memoryOverhead': '2g',
    'spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max': 1024,
    'spark.executor.instances': 16,
    'spark.executor.cores': 3,
    'spark.sql.session.timeZone':'Asia/Shanghai',
    'spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion':'false',
}
```

I have a dataframe

```
df = join_all([df_feat, df23, df_s1, df_s2, df_s3, df_ar1, df_ses], on=['store_id', 'product_id', 'ds'], how='left')
```

df_s1, df23 is looks like 
[image]

There is a big problem obstruct me moving to the next task.

`df.show() , df.toPandas() , df.count()` would fail if I filter by some condition, for example:

Success :

- df.show(10, 0)
- df.filter('product_id="dace8cc8-d7cc-47f7-a74c-4c8aff1914d3"').show()
- df.filter('store_id="40a1c9d7-15dd-4947-aa54-66dbd7e9c724"').show()

Error when filter by store_id and product_id

- df.filter('store_id="40a1c9d7-15dd-4947-aa54-66dbd7e9c724"').filter('product_id="dace8cc8-d7cc-47f7-a74c-4c8aff1914d3"').show()

detail:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-6b99148956e2> in <module>
----> 1 df.filter('store_id="40a1c9d7-15dd-4947-aa54-66dbd7e9c724"').filter('product_id="dace8cc8-d7cc-47f7-a74c-4c8aff1914d3"').show()

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    376         """
    377         if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 378             print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    379         else:
    380             print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3649.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 11 in stage 1167.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 11.3 in stage 1167.0 (TID 27777, dc45, executor 22): org.apache.spark.memory.SparkOutOfMemoryError: Unable to acquire 116 bytes of memory, got 0
    at org.apache.spark.memory.MemoryConsumer.throwOom(MemoryConsumer.java:157)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.MemoryConsumer.allocatePage(MemoryConsumer.java:119)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter.acquireNewPageIfNecessary(UnsafeExternalSorter.java:383)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter.insertRecord(UnsafeExternalSorter.java:407)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.insertRow(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage212.sort_addToSorter_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage212.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:624)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RowIteratorFromScala.advanceNext(RowIterator.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinScanner.advancedBufferedToRowWithNullFreeJoinKey(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinScanner.<init>(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:686)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1176)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1167)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1102)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1167)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$11.apply(Executor.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1363)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:413)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1890)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:929)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2111)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2060)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2049)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:740)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2081)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2102)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3383)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2544)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2758)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor146.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.memory.SparkOutOfMemoryError: Unable to acquire 116 bytes of memory, got 0
    at org.apache.spark.memory.MemoryConsumer.throwOom(MemoryConsumer.java:157)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.MemoryConsumer.allocatePage(MemoryConsumer.java:119)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter.acquireNewPageIfNecessary(UnsafeExternalSorter.java:383)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter.insertRecord(UnsafeExternalSorter.java:407)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.insertRow(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage212.sort_addToSorter_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage212.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:624)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.RowIteratorFromScala.advanceNext(RowIterator.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinScanner.advancedBufferedToRowWithNullFreeJoinKey(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinScanner.<init>(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:686)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.SortMergeJoinExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(SortMergeJoinExec.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ZippedPartitionsRDD2.compute(ZippedPartitionsRDD.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:337)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$7.apply(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1176)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1167)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1102)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1167)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$11.apply(Executor.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1363)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:413)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Then I tried fitler first, however this successed ...

```
df = join_all([
df_feat.filter('store_id="40a1c9d7-15dd-4947-aa54-66dbd7e9c724"').filter('product_id="dace8cc8-d7cc-47f7-a74c-4c8aff1914d3"'),
df23.filter('store_id="40a1c9d7-15dd-4947-aa54-66dbd7e9c724"').filter('product_id="dace8cc8-d7cc-47f7-a74c-4c8aff1914d3"'),
df_s1.filter('store_id="40a1c9d7-15dd-4947-aa54-66dbd7e9c724"').filter('product_id="dace8cc8-d7cc-47f7-a74c-4c8aff1914d3"'),
df_s2.filter('store_id="40a1c9d7-15dd-4947-aa54-66dbd7e9c724"').filter('product_id="dace8cc8-d7cc-47f7-a74c-4c8aff1914d3"'),
df_s3.filter('store_id="40a1c9d7-15dd-4947-aa54-66dbd7e9c724"').filter('product_id="dace8cc8-d7cc-47f7-a74c-4c8aff1914d3"'),
df_ar1.filter('store_id="40a1c9d7-15dd-4947-aa54-66dbd7e9c724"').filter('product_id="dace8cc8-d7cc-47f7-a74c-4c8aff1914d3"'),
df_ses.filter('store_id="40a1c9d7-15dd-4947-aa54-66dbd7e9c724"').filter('product_id="dace8cc8-d7cc-47f7-a74c-4c8aff1914d3"'),
], on=['store_id', 'product_id', 'ds'], how='left')


df.filter('store_id="40a1c9d7-15dd-4947-aa54-66dbd7e9c724"').filter('product_id="dace8cc8-d7cc-47f7-a74c-4c8aff1914d3"').show()
```

spark webui

[image]

### [image]

I have completely no idea where this error come from , this error doesn't make sence . How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you mention `spark.driver.memory` property value in the question?

Comment: @Saurabh updated , doesn't look like a memory error though spark complained .

Comment: It's worth to try with increased memory I guess or else you can monitor the usage of memory that whether it's consuming all 5GB or not before throwing the error. So the picture would be more clear.

Comment: @Saurabh Update some webui message .  `df.show()` return 20 rows by default, should not get memory error even in very low memory .

Comment: Try to increase the executor memory `spark.executor.memory`, `spark.executor.memoryOverhead`. Even though you are just getting a sample of 20 rows from the result dataframe, it is possible that the intermediate joining operations requires large memory on a executor. I had similar issue and increasing memory helped me to get thru.

Comment: Alternatively, increasing `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` or `spark.default.parallelism` may also help to reduce the size of data processed by each executor at a time. See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704156/what-is-the-difference-between-spark-sql-shuffle-partitions-and-spark-default-pa).