# How to identify how many partitions will be there for a dataset?

Tags: apache-spark

How many number of partitions will be there if I have 100 gb of data in spar?
If someone says we have 20 will that be enough for the memory

Comment: Hi Prateek, wellcome to SO. Please, read this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42171499/get-current-number-of-partitions-of-a-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

The number of partitions depends on the data source in use. For file-based data sources that use HDFS as a storage there will be as many partitions as there are blocks. Other data sources can report this requirement differently (based on their own internal logic).